# SharePoint online list forms customization

Tags: sharepoint-online

In SharePoint online, we can customize the forms and implement functionality using PowerApps, SPFX , a part from these 2 options do we have any other option with which we can customize the forms and functionality.

Comment: Do you have any further questions about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO.

And Power Apps is the most recommended way to easily customize the form for a SharePoint list or SharePoint document library, also, will fully replace InfoPath.